# How to fix Sort()?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, qsort

I tried to implement a stack on an array and its Hoare quick sort, but for some reason it doesn't work. Throws an exception on the line `mid = arr[(left + right) / 2]; N_op += 4;`. How to fix this error? And are there any errors in the implementation? (N_op - operation counter)

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
const int MAX_SIZE = 3000;

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Stack
{
public:
    T* arr;
    int size;
    unsigned long long int N_op;

    Stack()
    {
        arr = new T[MAX_SIZE];
        size = 0;
    }

    void Push(int x)
    {
        arr[size++] = x;
        N_op += 5;
    }

    void Pop()   
    {
        size--;
        N_op += 2;
    }

    T Top() 
    {
        N_op += 3;
        return arr[size - 1];
    }

    T Size()
    {
        N_op++;
        return size;
    }

    void Sort(int N)
    {
        int mid, left, right, l, r;
        mid = left = right = l = r = 0; N_op += 6;

        Push(N - 1); N_op += 2;
        Push(0); N_op++;

        do {
            left = Top(); N_op += 2;
            Pop(); N_op++;
            right = Top(); N_op += 2;
            Pop(); N_op++;
            {
                mid = arr[(left + right) / 2]; N_op += 4;
                l = left; N_op++;
                r = right; N_op++;
                while (l < r) 
                {
                    N_op++;

                    while (arr[l] < mid) 
                    {
                        l++;
                        N_op += 4;
                    }
                    while (mid < arr[r])
                    {
                        r--;
                        N_op += 4;
                    }

                    if (l <= r)
                    {
                        swap(arr[l], arr[r]);
                        l++;
                        r--;
                        N_op += 9;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (left < r)
            {
                Push(r);
                Push(left);
                N_op += 3;
            }

            if (l < right)
            {
                Push(right);
                Push(l);
                N_op += 3;
            }
        }
        while (Size() != -1);
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i, t_s, t_f;

    int Key[3000];
    int N = 300;
    Stack<int> stack;

    for (i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
        Key[i] = rand() % 999;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int z = N - 300; z < N; z++)
            stack.Push(Key[z]);

        stack.N_op = 0;
        t_s = GetTickCount64();
        stack.Sort(N);
        t_f = GetTickCount64();

        cout << "Номер сортировки: " << i + 1 << " | Количество отсортированных элементов: " << N << " | Время сортировки (ms): " << t_f - t_s << " | Количество операций (N_op): " << stack.N_op << endl;
        N += 300;
    }
}
```

Comment: These kinds of errors get fixed all the time by using a debugger to run the malfunctioning code one line at a time, inspecting the values of all variables, as they change, and seeing exactly what the program does, and why. Have you tried using your debugger, what did your debugger show you? Are the values of these variables what they should be, at this point, and if not why not?

Comment: You have a buffer overflow. https://godbolt.org/z/rd6fnaac4